# How do I convert dd/mm/yy into date datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, date-conversion

I am able to convert the following to a `varchar` type

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),'01/02/14',103)
```

I am getting an error while converting the above date to a `date` data type

```
SELECT Convert(date,'01/02/14',103)
```

I got the error saying

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I also tried the following but didn't work.

```
SELECT Convert(date,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),'01/02/14',103),103)
```

How can I convert to a `date` type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this for `dd/mm/yy` format:

```
SELECT Convert(date,'01/02/14',3);
```

or this for `dd/mm/yyyy` format:

```
SELECT Convert(date,'01/02/2014',103);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `103` format from the outer `Convert`.

```
SELECT convert(date,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),'01/02/14',103))
```

or simply without any format you can `convert` to date

```
SELECT Convert(date,'01/02/14')
```

Comment: @ShilpaPraneesh Calm down its not my **DV**. Don't assume things

Answer (score 0):

try `cast`

```
select cast('01/02/14' as date)
```

Comment: Its working. But I have a doubt. How do we know 14 is 2014 or 1914?

Comment: May be it takes current century.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Convert(date,'01/02/2014',103);
```

(or).

```
SELECT Convert(date,'01/02/14',3);
```

103 is used for YYYY format. If you want to convert YY format, use 3.